# Why do my "LINQ to SQL" ID's not synchronize?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, associations

I built my LINQ to SQL-file out of Tables in my .mdf, where the table "Measurement" is associated (One to One) with a "Experiment_Info"-table. While testing my application I entered some "Measurement"-entries. So the autoincrement counted up ID's for the tables. It is only afterwards that I started adding Entries with "Experiment_Info"-tables.

Both are created correctly, but the ID's of "Measurement"-tables are never equal to those of the "Experiment_Info"-tables, because the Measurement-ID's have already been counted up.

So when I am am calling LINQ join statements like:

```
bs.DataSource = 
    from m in measDAL.getMeasurements()
    join i in measDAL.getExperimentInfo() on m.Measurementid equals i.ExperimentInfoID
    select new { 
        m.Measurementid, 
        m.MeasurementName, 
        i.DateTime, 
        i.Project 
    };
```

Does 'equal' really mean '==' in this case? That would mean I would have to somehow reset all ID's in my database, wouldn't I?

Are my conclusions right? If they are how can this resetting be done?

Plus I want to show how I add entries to the database, because I suppose that could also be the issue. When I am adding entries in a 'One to Many' relationship it works like:

```
newMeasurement.SpectrumSet.Add(newSet);
```

In case of 'Experiment_Info' where I have a 'One to One' relationship, I do it like this:

```
Measurement newMeasurement = new Measurement();
newMeasurement.MeasurementName = name;

ExperimentInfo exInfo = new ExperimentInfo();
newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo = exInfo;


newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo.Analyze = analysis;
newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo.DateTime = dateTime;
newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo.DonorAge = donorAge;
newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo.Project = project;
newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo.Treatment = treatment;
newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo.MediaType = mediatype;
newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo.DonorAge = donorAge;
newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo.Passage = Passage;
newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo.Objective = objective;
newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo.Substrate = substrate;
newMeasurement.ExperimentInfo.Power = power;

measurements.InsertOnSubmit(newMeasurement);

measDAL.context.SubmitChanges();
```

I hope I could provide enough information about my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your database are `m.Measurementid` and `i.ExperimentInfoID` btoh auto-increment fields? If so this is the wrong way to do it. One of your tables should have a foreign key field which is the id of the entry in the other table. This should not be auto-incrememnted so you can insert whatever ID is correct.

Comment: This also counts for 'One to Many' relations I suppose?

Comment: Yes. A basic principle of database design is that any table that refers to another table should do so by using the primary key of one table and a foreign key in the other table. So yes, when in a one to many then in the "many" table you would have a "parentID" or something that is non-unique and allows you to reference the "one" table.

Comment: So I would have to always set the i.ID = m.ID. Isn't that a problem with one to many? Because then I would have several tables with same ID's?

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to say. Maybe I'm not explaining myself well but sadly comments aren't a good place for deep conversation. Googling for "foreign key" will be a good start probably. But as a brief example I might have three tables, Order, Address and Item. Each of these has its own ID. The order table might additionally have field "AddressID" that contains an ID from the Address table. It migth have duplicate values in this column but that's ok, it just means many orders are going to the same address. The Items table might also have an OrderID marking which order it is part of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a one-to-one relationship from what you've described, you've no relationship at all.

Have one table use an auto-incrementing id.

Have the other table use the IDs from that table, to set its id for defining the relationship (it *may* also have a separate auto id for identifying its own rows).

That way the database reflects the relationship between the tables.

Other tech will then use that relationship (linq2sql in this case, but it goes for other means of obtaining data from the db, too).